# Perl script error : 'script executable not found'

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute a `perl` script from Ubuntu (14.04 LTS). The script is `transOutput.pl` which calls an executable `pdb_trans`. However, when I run the script, I get the following error that `pdb_trans` is not found - see below.

```
toni@toni-ThinkPad-S3-S440:~/Desktop/PatchDock$ perl transOutput.pl output.txt 1 10

Ligand PDB: 7RSA.pdb

Receptor PDB: 2BNH.pdb

/home/toni/Desktop/PatchDock/pdb_trans  -0.04513 -0.08622 2.50522 50.82232 33.24094 -17.12692 < 7RSA.pdb >> output.txt.1.pdb

sh: 1: /home/toni/Desktop/PatchDock/pdb_trans: not found
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: can you please [edit] your question and include the output of `ls -l /home/toni/Desktop/PatchDock/pdb_trans` ?

Comment: Is there executable `/home/toni/Desktop/PatchDock/pdb_trans` in place?

Comment: And what does the title have to do with the body?

Comment: toni@toni-ThinkPad-S3-S440:~/Desktop/PatchDock$ ls -l /home/toni/Desktop/PatchDock/pdb_trans
-rwxr-xr-x 1 toni toni 353707 Aug 18  2004 /home/toni/Desktop/PatchDock/pdb_trans

Comment: Assuming that you are using this package [PatchDock](http://bioinfo3d.cs.tau.ac.il/PatchDock/), according to the readme file it seems that you will need to add the PatchDock directory to your path. Did you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Your perl script is trying to execute pdb_trans and it is using  "sh"

Likely you've already worked around this issue, but see [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378301/linux-executable-fails-with-file-not-found-even-though-the-file-is-there-and-i).

It appears that the executable, which you reported in comments above as being present can't find the dynamic libraries it needs to load